# Tableview invalid update on deleting bulk items from coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using core data fetchResultController as table data source. All works fine but running into peculiar issue on deleting bulk items from coredata. Getting bellow error and table becoming blank

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (339) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (338), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

I am using below code

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.dataTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.dataTableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.dataTableView;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:{
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
}
```

UPDATE:
Here is my numberOfRows method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if ([self fetchedResultsController]) {
        id sectionInfo = [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSInteger rowCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        return rowCount;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post your numberOfRowsInSection method

Comment: @ZHZ I just updated my que..please check

Comment: How are you updating the context? Inserting / moving at the same time as deleting? The error message says you effectively inserted without calling any insertion...

Comment: Code seems has no problem. The error says you inserted a row into the coreData. You should check the logic to confirm you DELETE a row from the coreData.